# Simple Webpack 4 + Babel 7 + React ClickHandler in ES6 syntax

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm just getting set up with a really simple React + Webpack 4 + Babel 7 following this great guide here - https://www.robinwieruch.de/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup/

I've got things running on my local host and created my first custom "hello world" style jsx component which is great!

Then I've tried to create a really simple clickHandler

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class testComponent extends Component {

ClickHandler = () => {
  console.log("I was called")
};

render() {

  return (
    <div>
      Test component test
      <button onClick={this.ClickHandler}>Click me</button>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This now causes my localhost to fall over with a blank page but I think my code is correct?

My guess was my usage of ES6 arrow function, even though I thought babel did it's thing and converted that if need .. so I've also tried ES5 syntax but still falls over with a blank screen

Feels like I've missed some understanding of what is actually happening here - I can't think where I would begin to debug this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably haven't set up babel to handle **class properties**.

You can install the following babel plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
```

...and then update your **.babelrc** file to use the plugin:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

Alternatively, you can change your code to remove the use of class properties:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class testComponent extends Component {

  clickHandler() {
    console.log("I was called")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Test component test
        <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly right - really useful stuff, thanks @steve Holgado